# Change ejb code to EntityManager code

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entitymanager

```
public class EjB3Configuration {

    private Ejb3Configuration configuration = null;

    protected PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo;

    public Ejb3Configuration getConfiguration() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (configuration == null) {
                Ejb3Configuration temp = new Ejb3Configuration();
                String previousValue = persistenceUnitInfo.getProperties().getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto");
                persistenceUnitInfo.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
                configuration = temp.configure(persistenceUnitInfo, new HashMap());
                configuration.getHibernateConfiguration().buildSessionFactory();
                if (previousValue != null) {
                    persistenceUnitInfo.getProperties().setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", previousValue);
                }
            }
        }
        return configuration;
    }

    public PersistenceUnitInfo getPersistenceUnitInfo() {
        return persistenceUnitInfo;
    }

    public void setPersistenceUnitInfo(PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo) {
        this.persistenceUnitInfo = persistenceUnitInfo;
    }

}
```

My call to ejb3 looks like following. How can i refactor the above code to entitymanager since ejb3 is removed from 4.3.10.Final hibernate version.

```
public PersistentClass getPersistentClass(final String targetClassName) {
        return ejb3Configuration.getConfiguration().getClassMapping(targetClassName);
    }
```

My call

Answer (score 0):

To create an `EntityManagerFactory` programatically you can this:

```
Properties properties = getProperties();
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistenceUnit", properties);
```